# Img,which is in wwwroot folder, won't show with tag <img> , why? ASP.NET and ANGULAR

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api

So, my project is in folder called 'UsedCarsShop', that folder holds two more folders:

1. Frontend

   - It holds 'UsedCarsShopFrontend' folder in which is Angular project located in
2. Backend

   - It holds 'CarWebShop' folder. In that folder there is another folder, same name, and backend
     asp.net project
     In the latest folder(CarWebShop) there is a folder called wwwroot/Photos. With each User's folder which contain images for every single Car they own.
     Now in my HTML document inside Angular app I have this img tag
     `<img src="/Photos/Bogi5/16/some_photo.jpg">`

inside of program.cs file I have this code:

````
using CarWebShop.Data;
using CarWebShop.Interfaces;
using CarWebShop.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICarRepository, CarsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAdverRepository, AdverRepository>();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    };
                });

var app = builder.Build();




// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseCors();

app.UseStaticFiles();



app.MapControllers();

app.Run();```


                      

As you can see, I am serving static files.
But Image do not show
Error is GET 'image path' (404) not found
````

Comment: Angular is might be prepending the base href when it is requesting the image. You can also place the images in the `assets` folder within the Angular app for handling static files.

Comment: Yes, but image i want to display rn, was uploaded from client side handled by specific controler. It wouldn't be good to hold images of everu single user in assests folder on frontend. Also, the image in example above was there just for test sake, i have static paths of every photo in my array in Angular, which will i later on dynamically display with certain bindings.

Comment: If you are running these 2 services as separate servers, i.e. `ng serve` and `dotnet run`, then the angular app would have to request images for the static files from the backend server. `<img src="https://localhost:5001/Photos/test.jpg"`

Comment: Auch, I literally tried that like hour ago, but instead of https://localhost:5167/ I've typed https://localhost:5168/ and it didn't work.
But now I've typed it correctly and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running these 2 services as separate servers, i.e. ng serve and dotnet run, then the angular app would have to request images for the static files from the backend server.

`<img src="https://localhost:5001/Photos/test.jpg" />`